# Producer Consumer with a transmitter

Tags: java, multithreading

This is interview question I encountered. And I'm really naive in multithread programming.

Here is the question: there are three threads: Producer, Consumer and Transmitter. Producer and Transmitter share a buffer called ProduceBuf. Consumer and Transmitter share the buffer called ConsumeBuf. Producer create a object and add it into ProduceBuf each time. Transmitter grab an object from the ProduceBuf and do some thing on the object then put it into the ConsumeBuf. Consumer consume the object in the ConsumeBuf.
And ProduceBuf can obtain 12 objects most. ConsumeBuf can obtain 6 objects most.

here is my try on this:

```
public class AdvanceCP {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         AdvanceCP ad = new AdvanceCP();
         ProduceBuf pb = ad.new ProduceBuf();
         ConsumeBuf cb = ad.new ConsumeBuf();

         Producer p = ad.new Producer(pb);
         Transmitter t = ad.new Transmitter(pb,cb);
         Consumer c = ad.new Consumer(cb);

         Thread tp = new Thread(p);
         Thread tt = new Thread(t);
         Thread tc = new Thread(c);

         tc.start();
         tt.start();
         tp.start();
    }

    class ProduceBuf {
        int index = 0;
        Integer[] buffer = new Integer[12];

        public synchronized void produce(){
            while(index == buffer.length){
                //buffer is full
                try {
                    this.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            int newInt = (int) (Math.random()*100);
            buffer[index] = newInt;
            System.out.println("Producing a new object."+newInt);
            index++;
            this.notify();
        }

        public synchronized Integer pop(){
            while(index==0) {
                try{
                    this.wait();
                } catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            index--;
            System.out.println("Transmitting a new object."+buffer[index]);
            return buffer[index];
        }
    }


    class ConsumeBuf {
        int index = 0;
        Integer[] buffer = new Integer[6];

        public synchronized void push(Integer newint){
            while(index==buffer.length){
                //buffer is full
                try {
                    this.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            buffer[index] = 0-newint;
            System.out.println("Transmitted a new object."+buffer[index]);
            index++;

            this.notify();
        }

        public synchronized Integer pop(){
            while(index==0) {
                try{
                    this.wait();
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            index--;
            System.out.println("Consuming a new object."+buffer[index]);
            return buffer[index];
        }
    }

    class Producer extends Thread{
        ProduceBuf pb =null;
        Producer(ProduceBuf p){
            pb = p;
        }
        public void run(){
            while(true) {
                pb.produce();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Transmitter extends Thread{
        ProduceBuf pb = null;
        ConsumeBuf cb = null;
        Transmitter(ProduceBuf p,ConsumeBuf c){
            pb = p;
            cb  =c;
        }
        public void run(){
            while(true){
                cb.push(pb.pop());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Consumer extends Thread{
        ConsumeBuf cb = null;
        Consumer(ConsumeBuf c){
            cb=c;
        }
        public void run(){
            while(true){
            cb.pop();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

However the console output seems like it doesn't act like multithreads:

```
Producing a new object.43
Transmitting a new object.43
Transmitted a new object.-43
Consuming a new object.-43
Producing a new object.39
Transmitting a new object.39
Transmitted a new object.-39
Consuming a new object.-39
Producing a new object.98
Transmitting a new object.98
Transmitted a new object.-98
Consuming a new object.-98
Producing a new object.64
Transmitting a new object.64
Transmitted a new object.-64
Consuming a new object.-64
Producing a new object.52
Transmitting a new object.52
Transmitted a new object.-52
Consuming a new object.-52
```

So I try to adjust sleep time of these three threads. If I add the consumer's sleep time to 500. The program would stuck after doing some thing:

```
 Producing a new object.77
Transmitting a new object.77
Transmitted a new object.-77
Consuming a new object.-77
Producing a new object.83
Transmitting a new object.83
Transmitted a new object.-83
Producing a new object.46
Transmitting a new object.46
Transmitted a new object.-46
Producing a new object.28
Transmitting a new object.28
Transmitted a new object.-28
Producing a new object.72
Transmitting a new object.72
Transmitted a new object.-72
Producing a new object.25
Transmitting a new object.25
Transmitted a new object.-25
Producing a new object.94
Transmitting a new object.94
Transmitted a new object.-94
Producing a new object.63
Transmitting a new object.63
Producing a new object.64
Producing a new object.13
Producing a new object.14
Consuming a new object.-94
Producing a new object.63
Producing a new object.87
Producing a new object.80
Producing a new object.49
Producing a new object.85
Producing a new object.35
Producing a new object.16
Producing a new object.34
Producing a new object.14
Consuming a new object.-25
Consuming a new object.-72
Consuming a new object.-28
Consuming a new object.-46
Consuming a new object.-83
```

I don't know where is the point. As a beginner to multithreading, I'm sure there is something I'm overlooking, and I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you do not notify the `push()` method in `consumer.pop()` method

So it goes like this
1-> There is a push in consumer
2-> The buffer is full, so the push goes in wait state
3-> The pop(consume thread) gets(remove) an object, and it doesn't tell push about this, so this is your problem as the output says the same thing.

So your pop in consume would be like this, (the pop of producer has different story).

```
public synchronized Integer pop(){
            while(index==0) {
                try{
                    this.wait();
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            index--;
            System.out.println("Consuming a new object."+buffer[index]);
            Integer res=buffer[index];// 
            this.notify();//MISSED
            return res;
        }
```

Also comment out all `sleep()` things to get more reliable outputs(limit the run/loops) or decrease them to small values and vary.

Comment: Ah, I missed the notify(). So careless.  So the solution itself is correct, right?

Comment: @FredXue looks right, but not enterprise, fair enough for an interview

Comment: Thank u very much!  give me a hint about an enterprise solution? ^ - ^

Comment: Considering a well designed and implemented `MOA` system, such as [`Active-MQ`](http://activemq.apache.org/)